# Android : How to import a database file from xml format into  sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to import an xml file into sqlite database. Actually i have base64 encoded the file and exported to internal storage. now, i have no problem with decoding the file but what i need is to replace the existing database file in sqlite with the decoded xml file containing the database in xml format.How to achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: can u be more descriptive about this ?

Comment: @Tintin: I have exported my database as export.xml to internal memory, with base64 encoded. this has to be replacing my existing database after decoding. i need a specific solution/ way to import and replace the existing db file with that decoded db file

Comment: So.. for starters, it's XML, why would you need to apply a transfer encoding such as Base64 to it? It's probably large enough already. Secondly, what's the schema like (you should consider attaching a sample to your question)?

Answer (score 0):

if your solution can be a manual solution you can do this steps:

1. decode base 64.
2. write a code that read xml and generate query
   (or export xml to csv format using excel or your own code)
3. import the this file to sqlite db using SQL Browser or similar tools.

is this your suitable answer?